# How to generate week ranges for a year in SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have to insert  `YEAR  WEEKNUMBER   STARTDATE   ENDDATE`  values to a datatable (say `weekrange`), if I pass 2011 as year.

Week range starts at `2011-03-28` to `2011-04-03`  (because in my database 2010 last week range ends with `2011-03-27`)

Like this I have to generate for 52 weeks.

I want to write a stored procedure, that takes only year as parameter. with this year I have to generate week ranges and insert into my table as shown above.

How can I do this ?

Regards, 
jn

Comment: Given that 50 years of week ranges would only occupy 2600 rows, why not generate all of the rows now that your database could conceivably need?

Comment: What are your rules for defining week numbers? If you may not have 53 weeks in some years, you're going to need to define rules about how to identify day 1 of week 1.

Answer (score 0):

The following will generate the data you need based on SQL server's week number definition (see the notes on `DATEPART(ww,...)` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)). Note that this will mean some years have 53 weeks.

```
DECLARE @year AS CHAR(4)
SET @year = '2011'

DECLARE @firstDay DATETIME
SET @firstDay = CAST(@year + '0101' AS DATETIME)

;WITH dayCTE 
AS 
(
    SELECT DATEADD(dd,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) - 1, @firstDay) AS yearday
    FROM    master.dbo.spt_values
)
,weekCTE
AS
(
    SELECT  yearday, 
            DATEPART(WW,yearday) AS weekno
    FROM dayCTE
    WHERE YEAR(yearday) = @year
)
SELECT  @year        AS [YEAR],
        weekno       AS WEEKNUMBER, 
        MIN(yearday) AS STARTDATE, 
        MAX(yearday) AS ENDDATE
FROM weekCTE
GROUP BY weekno
ORDER BY weekno
```

It's a side point, but I'd recommend renaming the `YEAR` column of your target table to something which isn't a T-SQL keyword.

Comment: In dayCTE, I do not understand why you're getting a row number for each row in master.dbo.spt_values. The table has 2346 rows, which are not related to any date range. To me, it looks like spt_values holds value ranges for various internal system types. Again, nothing to do with finding the number of days between two dates.

Comment: @EdwardJ.Stembler - as you'll see if you execute the code inside `dayCTE` on its own, `master.dbo.spt_values` is being used as a "numbers" or "tally" table to generate a series of sequential numbers. `spt_values` is often used for this (especially on forums) as it exists in all SQL server installations.